# Are these scenes from the Star Wars prequels reused in The Book of Boba Fett?

Tags: star-wars, boba-fett, the-book-of-boba-fett

In the series premiere of *The Book of Boba Fett*, Boba Fett is shown to be in some sort of recovery tank (similar to the one seen in *Empire Strikes Back* where Luke is recovering on Hoth). During this, he is shown to be dreaming about his past where multiple flashbacks are shown, two of which were:

**Flashback # 1**: Clash on Kamino (*one image below*). This was similar of Jango and Boba's escape from Tapoka city on Kamino right after a short fight between Boba and Obi-Wan Kenobi.

[image: Tapoka city on Kamino] 
 <sub>*Snapshot from Book of Boba Fett, click to enlarge*</sub>

**Flaskback # 2**: Battle of Geonosis (*one image below*). This was similar to the scene from *Attack of the Clones* after Jango was beheaded by Mace Windu.

[image: Boba holding Jango's helmet, Attack of the Clones]
 <sub>*Snapshot from Book of Boba Fett, click to enlarge*</sub>

Both these flashbacks were reminiscent of specific scenes from *Star Wars: Attack of the Clones*. So, were the scenes from these flashbacks actually repurposed/reused from the prequels?

Comment: I spotted that theyd tilted and zoomed them slightly

Comment: @Valorum yes, that was my first thought as well; change the prespective and edit some things in the background.. But the scenes from Kamino, never saw them in the *AotC*.

Comment: “some sort of recovery tank” — it’s described in dialogue as a Bacta Pod, although given Boba’s apparent experience of memory-based dreams in there, it’s likely Fennec accidentally bought a _Flashbacta Pod_ instead 

Comment: Note a distinction between being “in the film” versus possibility of being film footage, possibly shot but not edited into the final cut.

Answer (score 20):

### According to the actor, a new over the shoulder shot was created for the show, but the rest is from the original film.

In the video comparison below, the angle, framing and position of the actor in the scene is different to the film version:

Daniel Logan, the actor, [confirmed in a tweet](https://comicbook.com/starwars/amp/news/star-wars-book-of-boba-fett-attack-of-the-clones-flashback-daniel-logan/) that the over the shoulder shot was new, the rest of the footage was from the film

> Q. This shot wasn’t in AOTC. Was it unused footage or did they re-create this?
>
> **[@Daniel_Logan](https://twitter.com/Daniel_Logan/status/1476395133683712000)**: That particular over the shoulder shot is new. The rest of young #BobaFett is from the 2000 shoot in Australia.

Comment: I probably stand corrected. IMDB suggest the actor is the original young Boba Fett, appearing in archive footage. So it could be a different take, but the actor’s hairstyle looks quite different to me, and his legs look shorter.

Comment: A good find on the tweet. What about the Kamino footage?

Comment: +1 for the answer. Try to add the Kamino stuff if you find it, I’ll accept it. If not, let’s wait to see if we find something else from someone

Comment: @Shreedhar Thanks! I agree as you said above that the Kamino shots don’t initially look like they’re form AotC. I’m sure an answer will arrive soon!

Comment: I found a video on YouTube that claims both these scenes were unused shots from the prequels. However, it’s more of a “trust me, bro” sitch, no sources to support the claims 

Answer (score 3):

According to [Joanna Robinson](https://www.jowrotethis.com/) on [the Ringer-Verse podcast](https://www.theringer.com/2021/12/31/22861190/the-book-of-boba-fett-chapter-1-deep-dive) (from whom I stole the Flashbacta Pod joke above), the **Flashback #2** shot of young Boba with his father's helmet from *Attack of the Clones* [was partially reshot for *The Book of Boba Fett*](https://overcast.fm/+rewBOI9g8/1:14:20), to avoid re-using older computer-generated imagery that may not hold up so well against today's effects.

Comment: Who is Joanna Robinson, and where did she get this insider information from?

Comment: She’s an entertainment journalist; she doesn’t cite specific sources in the podcast, so I’m not sure.

Comment: I'm always dubious of quoting supposed '*Star Wars insiders*' who don't give their sources. They could easily just be [making it up](http://starwarshub.net/2019/03/03/the-original-star-wars-internet-troll-the-story-of-supershadow/).

Comment: @Valorum Could be, although no-one on the podcast mentioned the phrase “_Star Wars_ insiders”, and Joanna works for The Ringer covering this stuff and does actually interview TV creators, so I’d give claims like this from her some credibility.

Comment: @Oh sure, and the better answer above yours confirms some of what she's saying. so either she's read that article (or something similar) or her guesswork was accurate.

Comment: @Valorum Or she’s also spoken to someone involved in the production of the show.